# How to assert that a list does not contain something, with FEST?

Tags: java, testing, fest

I'm using [FEST](https://code.google.com/p/fest/) to write assertions in JUnit.

It's easy to assert that a list is containing some elements:

```
assertThat(list).contains(2,4);
```

But how to assert that the list is not containing something? Like:

```
assertThat(list).doesnotContain(3); // !!! no such method
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've just been having a browse through the source code for the version 1 branch and found this:

```
/**
 * Verifies that the actual group of objects does not contain the given objects.
 *
 * @param objects the objects that the group of objects should exclude.
 * @return this assertion object.
 * @throws AssertionError       if the actual group of objects is {@code null}.
 * @throws NullPointerException if the given array is {@code null}.
 * @throws AssertionError       if the actual group of objects contains any of the given objects.
 */
public final @Nonnull S excludes(@Nonnull Object... objects) {
    assertExcludes(objects);
    return myself();
}
```

I probably shouldn't make wild assumptions like this, but it's in the same class as your `contains` method (`ObjectGroupAssert`) and the Javadoc seems to describe the functionality you're looking for.

So I think, you would just need:

```
assertThat(list).excludes(5,7);
```

Comment: It works! The method name `excludes` is a little surprise to me

Comment: Huzzah! :) Yeah, `excludes` is new to me too, I'd've expected a `doesNotContain` variant.  But thinking about it, I like excludes, but it might sit better with includes as it's counter-part rather than contains.

Answer (score 0):

doesnotContain() method present in assertJ library.
F.e.

```
assertThat(usersList).doesNotContain(userDTO);
```